# ScalaTest: pass command line arguments to ScalaTest maven goal

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

How do I pass command line arguments to ScalaTest using its maven plugin? I was looking for something like TestNG's `delegateCommandSystemProperties` configuration, but the closest I could find in [ScalaTest documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) were:

- `argLine`: Option to specify additional JVM options to pass to the forked process
- `environmentVariables`: Additional environment variables to pass to the forked process
- `systemProperties`: Additional system properties to pass to the forked process

But isn't this redundant? For example if I want to pass `environment=development`, I need to specify the following in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Denvironment=${env}</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then run `mvn test -Denv=development`. Is there a simpler way to pass command line arguments to ScalaTest directly?

Comment: Upvoted this nearly twelve months ago. Still awaiting an answer. Bill (Venners) are you out there?

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for defining `<argLine>` in the pom.
But it's surely not intuitive to figure, nor well documented, just need to add a simple example usage into the docs.

All you need for passing system properties to a maven test is: `test -Dsuites=com.company.somepackage.SomeSpec "-DargLine=-Denv=env001 -Dgroup=default -DmaxTests=10"`.

For `environmentVariables` and `systemProperties` - there has got to be a simple syntax that works too.  Should be possible to figure from either trial and error or reading the source code if anyone's interested.  For my needs `argLine` is enough.